# Can I share an Office365 Group Calendar with external users?

Tags: office-365, office-online, outlook.com-calendar

I've enabled external sharing in the Office365 administrative area. Users can share their own calendars with external users, which simply emails them a generic iCal URL that anyone with the link can use. I'd like to generate one of these for a *group calendar*. The only way I've been able to get remotely close to this is to generate a URL that utilizes the API like so:

> https://user:password@outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users/groupname@example.com/calendarview

Obviously this requires the credentials, which is unacceptable in my use case.

Is this possible? If not, I'll have to setup a proxy.